# Difference between Main Account and Account 1

Tags: wallets

Is there a Difference between "Main Account" and "Account 1", because I lost my password for the Main Account, which has no Eth on it? Do I need the password for the main account in any way (technical or maybe in the future for updates etc)?
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Difference between "Main Account" and "Account 1",

It depends what you mean by "Main Account".

The accounts are 0-indexed, meaning your "first" account is `web3.eth.accounts[0]`, your "second" account is `web3.eth.accounts[1]`, and so on.

Your coinbase account is the account to which any mined ether are sent. By default this will be account `0`, but you can change it to point to any of your other accounts, e.g. `web3.eth.coinbase = web3.eth.accounts[3]`.

---

**Danger: Back-up your keystore before following the below part**

If you want to remove any of your accounts, remove the associated folder from your `~/.ethereum/keystore/` directory. Removing your unused `account[0]` will cause any later accounts to shuffle up, meaning your old `account[1]` will become your new `account[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

They are separate accounts.

If there is no eth in "Main Account," and you don't plan on ever accessing that address, then you will not need its password for anything.

Answer (score 0):

All accounts are equal! But if you are mining, make sure you have the keys to your coinbase account.